# Consultas genericas en SQLSERVER

Tags: c#, sql-server

Buen día quisiera saber si alguien, ha hecho alguna ves, algo asi como un IDE de sql server desde C#.

Me explico, he creado un entorno de SQLServer Web (En MVC), para la administración remota, y tengo toda la parte visual, me falta la parte mas importante la ejecucion de consultas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera saber si saben de alguna DLL o algún pedazo de código para hacer funcionar la parte de ejecución de consultas SQL, todo lo demás ya funciona, Estaré muy agradecido de vuestras respuestas.

Comment: He estado estudiando y practicando MVC; una vez que creas el Modelo (clase) el mismo IDE (Visual Studio) te ayuda a crear el controller, views (agregar, eliminar...) casí no es necesario meterle mano salvo quieras hacer cambios a la interfaz; te sugiero mires en MVA (Microsoft Virtual Academy) allí hay cursos muy buenos (en inglés y subtitulados en español) te sugiero "Introducción a ASP.NET MVC" te llevara de la mano y veras que casi no se requiere hacer mucho para obtener el A,B,C con la BD; incluso ya trae casi que para usar el logeo, creación de cuentas.... y demas.

Comment: Hola @RobertoLeónOramas Esta en ASP MVC 5.0 con Razor, el problema como expongo es la pregunta, la ejecución indistinta de sentencias que el cliente escriba en el cuadro de texto para ingresar el código SQL.

Comment: saludos Gabriel, veo que tienes un gran potencial como desarrollador para haberte tomado el tiempo de desarrollar un software de ese nivel, aquí tienes https://sqlwebadmin.codeplex.com/ espero te sea de utilidad :D éxitos bro!

Comment: aquí encontré otro más: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4803534/3613462 por cierto, una vez que hagas funcionar tu pregunta, agrega la solución para que más personas puedan crecer con la comunidad, gracias por colaborar :D

Comment: Hola @fredyfx Revise y ese Web no es muy completo que digamos, también que pertenece al SQL 2005 y tiene muchos errores, trate de hacerlo compilar hace una semana y me demore mas tratándolo de hacer correr y decidi programarlo a mi manera, ahora el link de SOF demorare revisando cada link, Gracias.

Comment: De nada hermano :D éxitos!

Comment: Hola, has probado a usar los ensamblados de `SQL Server Management Objects (SMO)` ? Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.dll
Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll
Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum.dll

Comment: Puedes ver mas información sobre SMO en [Overview SMO](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/overview-smo)

Comment: @SergioParraGuerra si, pero no sé como hacer para diferenciar una consulta escalar de una con resultados sin hacer 2 consultas.